# How to change span value from a html input which has been appended using ajax call?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal which is triggered on  click and modal data is added by ajax request to my php file. After the ajax call, when the modal shows,I want the span values in my modal to change simultaneously to the input field of my modal.

I have tried this javascript code but it isn't working after the ajax call.

```
$("#j").on("change keypress input", function() {
     $("#total").value( $("#j").val() );
     var a=($(this).val()*2.37).toFixed(2);
     $("#possible").html(a);

});
```

My modal:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="modal-body" class='form-row has-danger border-bottom mb-30'>

    </div>  
    <div class='col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 border-bottom form-row mt-15 mb-10'>
       <div class='col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 text-left'>
           <strong>Total Jobs</strong>
       </div> 
       <div class='col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-right'>
           <strong><span id='total'></span></strong> //want to change value of this based on input field added from php page
       </div>
     </div> 
     <div class='col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 form-row '>
           <div class='col-xl-8 col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 text-left'>
                <strong>Possible Jobs</strong>
           </div> 
           <div class='col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 text-right'>
                <strong><span id='possible'></span></strong> //want to change value of this based on input field added from php page
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

My ajax call:

```
function job(job_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url : "job.php", //this is my php file where echo for the modal happens
        type : "post",
        dataType:"text",
        data : {
            stake_id: bet_id
        },
        success : function (a){
            $('#modal-body').html(a);//adding echo part to my modal
            $('#RequestModal').modal('show');
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get it all but I have noticed you are trying to get value of span throught val() function , you should use html() or text() instead to get the value and use it in wherever you want

Comment: An input(text type) is added to the modal when I am calling the ajax to my php file and after that the modal appears. What I want to do is, after the modal call,any input change in the input tag will result in changing value of the spans